# Evaluate double integral $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-4|x|}^{|x|} e^{x+y} \, dy \, dx$ involving absolute values

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I have the following question on my assignment, and I have no idea how to take this integral. I tried using the [online integral calculator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/), but it says the function is unintegratable (yet it spits out this number: $3.679137994987764$, which my homework says is wrong, and I don't understand how it got). However, my homework insists there is an answer.

The problem is $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-4|x|}^{|x|} e^{x+y} \, dy \, dx.$$

I was able to do the internal integral, and get

$$\int_{-1}^1 e^{x+|x|}-e^{x-4|x|} \, dx$$

However, I have no idea what to do from here. Do I split the integral up into two pieces (one from $-1$ to $0$, and the other from $0$ to one), and treat this problem in a similar manner to $\int|x| \,dx$?

**Edit:** I tried solving it like Zain Patel's answer demonstrates, but the program isn't accepting his answer, nor the one I get.

Breaking the integral up, we get: $$\int_{-1}^{0}e^{x-x}-e^{5x}dx+\int_{0}^{1}e^{x+x}-e^{-3x}dx$$

Taking the integral, I get the following, which is different than Zain's answer. $$x-\frac{1}{5}e^{5x}|_{-1}^{0}+\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}|_{0}^{1}$$

Solving, I get
$$\frac{-1}{30}+\frac{1}{5e^5}+\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{1}{3e^3}$$

Does anyone see where a potential error is?

**Edit 2:** Tony K pointed out that my last integral was incorrect. It should be positive, not negative.

$$\frac{-1}{30}+\frac{1}{5e^5}+\frac{e^2}{2}+\frac{1}{3e^3}$$

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the way to handle this integral.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/2rY3Tw0) agrees with your calculator.

Comment: A warning in particular: online homework tools like WebWork are coded very simply. If you copy-and-pasted $3.679137994987764$ into your homework program, it likely hated the answer because of a floating point error (in other words, you gave more decimal places than the program ever anticipated anyone would enter). Try using less decimals, particularly maybe three decimal places.

Comment: Other times online homework systems reject decimal approximations if an exact answer is possible in closed form.  WebAssign would expect an exact answer in terms of powers of $e$ here.

Comment: The integral of $-e^{-3x}$ is $\frac13 e^{-3x}$, not $-\frac13 e^{-3x}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precisely! We have $$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1 e^{x+|x|} - e^{x - 4|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{-1}^0 e^{x \color{red}{-}x}-e^{x\color{red}{+}4x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1 e^{x\color{green}{+}x} - e^{x\color{green}{-}4x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ & = \int_{-1}^0 1 - e^{5x} \, \mathrm{d}x+\int_0^1 e^{2x} -e^{-3x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ & =  \bigg[x-\frac{1}{5}e^{5x}\bigg]_{-1}^0 + \bigg[\frac{1}{2}e^{2x} + \frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}\bigg]_0^1 \\ & = \frac{4}{5}-\frac{e^{-5}}{5} + \frac{e^2}{2} + \frac{e^{-3}}{3} - \frac{5}{6}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! The process makes sense to me now, but the program isn't liking this answer. When I tried integrating it, I got $\frac{-1}{30}+\frac{1}{5e^5}+\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{1}{3e^3}$. It didn't accept my answer either.

Comment: @TobyTobyo your answer is certainly correct - thanks for that, just fixed my typo. Have you tried inputting a (short) decimal form into the program?  Are you inputting the expression with the proper bracketing around the exponents, etc...?

Comment: I'm checking with my professors to see if there could possibly be an error with the program. It's flagged correct answers as incorrect in the past!

Comment: The integral of $e^{5x}$ is $\frac15 e^{5x}$, not $\frac15 e^{-5x}$.

Comment: $\dfrac{e^5}{5}$ in the last line is still wrong.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks - completely lost track of my signs there.

Comment: Only one more mistake to fix in that term (yes, srsly), and you're there!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the easiest thing to do is split the integral at zero: on $[-1,0)$, $\lvert x \rvert = -x$ so one has $e^{0}-e^{5x}$, and on $(0,1]$, $\lvert x \rvert = x$, so the integrand is $ e^{2x}-e^{-3x} $.

Comment: And then $e^0$ is just treated as a constant, correct?

Comment: @TobyTobyo: $e^0$ is as constant as $\sqrt{5}$.  More to the point, $e^0=1$.